# Checking SPF in PHP

Tags: php, regex, spf

An IT service provider have to write our SPF changes on Internet, I just mail my instructions.

I created a program in PHP to check in one click all my domains, to see if it is correct (sometimes a bad copy-paste include bad characters)

I tried to test the SPF with

```php
if (strpos(strtolower($spf), 'v=spf')
```

but this doesn't check bad characters

I tried with a preg_match but it's not working

A spf record can contain only these characters
[a-z] [0-9] . ? - ~ (space) and must start with v=spf

all other characters must echo "Invalid syntax"

Example:

```php
$spfdata='v=spf1 mx 1.2.3.4 ~all';

if (preg_match('/(v=spf)([a-z0-9-~?.])/i', $spfdata)){
    echo "SPF seems to be ok";
} else {
    echo "Invalid syntax";
}
```

This doesn't work it always says "ok" even if I type a bad character.

Comment: You did not put any quantifier after the character class - so this looks for one single character that matches the class only. And since you did not anchor your pattern to the beginning and end, _anything_ is allowed after that one character.

Comment: There are PHP libraries to help validate SPF, such as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749957/how-to-validate-spf-records-with-php, why not use one instead of rolling your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'/^v=spf[a-z0-9~? .-]+$/i'
```

Or, if you want to allow any kind of whitespace:

```
'/^v=spf[a-z0-9~?\s.-]+$/i'
```

PHP code:

```
$spfdata='v=spf1 mx 1.2.3.4 ~all';

if (preg_match('/^v=spf[a-z0-9~?\s.-]+$/i', $spfdata)){
    echo "SPF seems to be ok";
} else {
    echo "Invalid syntax";
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/mYXjs)

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `v=spf` - a literral text
- `[a-z0-9~?\s.-]+` - 1+ ASCII letters, digits, `~`, `?`, whitespaces, `.` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks  @Wiktor Stribizew in the regex a just remplace the \s by a normal whitespace and also add : and + that I forgot (SPF can contain those characters)

Comment: I had some weird response when spf contain the dash
We have to add an escape charactere for the - like so:
`'/^v=spf[a-z0-9~?\s.\-]+$/i'`

Comment: Why? What was the exact input?

Comment: it said Invalid syntax instead of ok the input was something like v=spf1 mx 1.2.3.4 -all (which is valid)

Comment: You should check for any invisible chars at the start/end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but when I delete the first block (v=spf) the regex seems to be good
I tried a lot of differents things and finally this works (I invert the logic with the ^)

So the regex says "if your are NOT in the bracket expression you are ok"

```
$spfdata='v=spf1 mx 1.2.3.4 ~all';

if (preg_match('#[^a-z0-9 :\+=.\-~\?]#', $spfdata)){
    echo "Invalid syntax";
} else {
    echo "SPF seems to be ok";
}
```